# how to make a 3D opengl drawn object respond to clicks

Tags: c#, opentk

I have a cube in openTK (openGL C#) and I want it to respond to mouse clicks. Is there any inbuilt function to do this? I would be very glad to have some help on the subject as I cannot find the right keywords to find it in google. All I need is a function that would return the area it currently occupies on the 2D screen. Then I could find if the mouse has clicked on this area. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: One can split hairs if feeling bored but want to say something.

Comment: what do you mean "split hairs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL does not have a built-in function for object picking. The [Picking example](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/blob/develop/Source/Examples/OpenGL/1.x/Picking.cs) shows one way to implement this in OpenTK. Depending on your project, there may be simpler or faster ways to do this.